# PHP imap_open wont connect

Tags: php, imap

Trying to use the PHP function imap_open to connect to my gmail account, here is the code:

```
$mailboxpath = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX";
$username = "email@gmail.com";
$password = "password";

$imap = imap_open($mailboxpath, $username, $password);
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/sf/pa/ys/sfpayslips.info/public_html/test/index.php on line 6
```

Not using XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

Try using `{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}`

Comment: This is in your local machine ? or is in remote ? if remote; try local.

Comment: Maybe it's problem on your **gmail** account, i've tested the same script and are ok (no error thrown), have you tried another gmail account ? just for testing.

Comment: Thats really strange, as I have tried this script in work on their imap and it throws the same error. Just tried a different gmail account and I get the same error...

Comment: Connection timed out, guessing Google are blocking the login as it may seem suspicious to them

Comment: Have you checked that the ports aren't fire walled?  Log onto a shell and attempt to connect to port 993.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different form of account like Outlook for example. Also try this:
`{mail.domain.com:143/notls}INBOX`.